# link_to not passing params properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

the view

```
<td><%= link_to "+1", :controller => :profiles, :action => :addpoints, :profile_id => profile.id, :task_id => @task.id%></td>
```

When trying to access profile.id via :profile_id rails returns an error, the id was not passed at all. How do I fix this? What's the best way to pass two params through two models? 
 rake routes

```
 Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                           Controller#Action
         welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)              welcome#index
     static_pages_home GET    /static_pages/home(.:format)          static_pages#home
static_pages_dashboard GET    /static_pages/dashboard(.:format)     static_pages#dashboard
  static_pages_pending GET    /static_pages/pending(.:format)       static_pages#pending
static_pages_taskcompleted GET    /static_pages/taskcompleted(.:format) static_pages#taskcompleted
           tasks_index GET    /tasks/index(.:format)                tasks#index
        tasks_complete GET    /tasks/complete(.:format)             tasks#complete
          tasks_delete GET    /tasks/delete(.:format)               tasks#delete
    profiles_addpoints GET    /profiles/addpoints(.:format)         profiles#addpoints
        profiles_index GET    /profiles/index(.:format)             profiles#index
                  root GET    /                                     static_pages#home
      new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)              devise/sessions#new
          user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)              devise/sessions#create
  destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)             devise/sessions#destroy
         user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)             devise/passwords#create
     new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)         devise/passwords#new
    edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)        devise/passwords#edit
                       PATCH  /users/password(.:format)             devise/passwords#update
                       PUT    /users/password(.:format)             devise/passwords#update
  cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)               devise/registrations#cancel
     user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                      devise/registrations#create
 new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)              devise/registrations#new
edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                 devise/registrations#edit
                       PATCH  /users(.:format)                      devise/registrations#update
                       PUT    /users(.:format)                      devise/registrations#update
                       DELETE /users(.:format)                      devise/registrations#destroy
                 tasks GET    /tasks(.:format)                      tasks#index
                       POST   /tasks(.:format)                      tasks#create
              new_task GET    /tasks/new(.:format)                  tasks#new
             edit_task GET    /tasks/:id/edit(.:format)             tasks#edit
                  task GET    /tasks/:id(.:format)                  tasks#show
                       PATCH  /tasks/:id(.:format)                  tasks#update
                       PUT    /tasks/:id(.:format)                  tasks#update
                       DELETE /tasks/:id(.:format)                  tasks#destroy
              profiles GET    /profiles(.:format)                   profiles#index
                       POST   /profiles(.:format)                   profiles#create
           new_profile GET    /profiles/new(.:format)               profiles#new
          edit_profile GET    /profiles/:id/edit(.:format)          profiles#edit
               profile GET    /profiles/:id(.:format)               profiles#show
                       PATCH  /profiles/:id(.:format)               profiles#update
                       PUT    /profiles/:id(.:format)               profiles#update
                       DELETE /profiles/:id(.:format)               profiles#destroy
```

Comment: What Rails version are you working in?

Comment: @dmtri.com Rails 4.01

Comment: Can do you `rake routes` and post the result? Also what error is it returning?

Comment: Edited the question. Just now the error was that the controller does not detect an id, meaning it was not passed on. Now it just doesn't work (clicking on the link does nothing).

Comment: A suggestion, in group development throw in binding_of_user and better_errors gems so that you can get a console in the browser on errors. It might be that the params just aren't arranged/named like you thought they are.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `profile.id` with `@profile.id`. Verify that profile is actually an instance. A `nil` value may be being passed in (as opposed to things being wired incorrectly).

Comment: Have tried that, doesn't work. P.S. because the link is rendered in a `do.each` structure.

Answer (score 0):

Can we see the method content ? 
If the error is about the id, the route is correct. What's in `params[:profile_id]` ? We need more info here..

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you wanted to do in Rails 4 way.

```
<%= link_to "+1", profiles_addpoints_path(:profile_id => profile.id, :task_id => @task.id) %>
```

That code above will call `addpoints` method in `profiles` controller with parameter `{:profile_id => profile.id, :task_id => @task.id}`. You can access parameter like this.
`params[:profile_id]` and `params[:task_id]`.

Another thing that's worrysome about your code is that in the routes.rb, `profiles_addpoints` route is called via `GET` HTTP verb. This is potentially dangerous because Google search bots will visit these paths and result in a spike in upvotes. Respect HTTP convention and use `PUT`.